# Edited-How can I solve polynomial recurrences like $f(n+1)=\frac{2f(n)}{f(n)+1}$

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

Can anybody tell me the systematic way of solving this recurrence.

$$f(n+1)=\frac{2f(n)}{f(n)+1}$$

I looked over the internet, but could not find the answer. Thanks

{Edit- I am sorry, previously I posted the problem $f(n)=\frac{2f(n)}{f(n)+1}$. Please note that this is not the problem that I intended to ask,  and it is not even a recurrence. I have updated my post to reflect the correct problem.}

Now, from what I learnt in high school and college so far, this problem would have been solvable if there was no $f(n)$ in the denominator on the other side. For e.g $f(n+1)=2f(n)$ Then, I would have simply used recursion or Master's Theorem(in case it was applicable). But I do not know how to solve a recurrence like this. I would really appreciate if anybody could point me to the right direction.

Comment: Can't you just cancel $f(n)$ on both sides and conclude $f(n)$ is either $0$ or $1$?

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is you have to be careful when you divide by zero "in disguise". In this case, it worked out, but "cancelling" implies that the term cancelled is not zero - otherwise we'd have things like $0=0\;\Rightarrow\; 0\cdot 1=0\cdot 2\;\Rightarrow\; 1=2$. What that means is that, in general, you have to consider whether 0 is a solution separately.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I would suggest you to explain a little bit how you tried to solve it, so other people could help you better. If not, probably the question will receive a lot of negative votes. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @iadvd. I have added more detail. The problems also had a typo which I have now corrected.

Answer (score 1):

We have  $$f(n)[f(n)-1]=0$$

$$\implies f(n)=0,1\forall n$$